# Sharing attachments using Gmail sharing extension

Tags: ios, gmail, uiactivityviewcontroller, ios-extensions

I'm attempting to share an image in my app using `Gmail sharing extension`. Everything works okay except for the recipient of the email who receives a malformed file.

Sample project can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sonjvui2pej86s8/Gmail%20Extension%20Error%20demo.zip?dl=0).

Using `iOS 8.3`, `Xcode 4.6.3`, `Gmail 4.0`

Sharing code looks like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[imageData]
                                                                             applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**This presents the activity sheet like this:**

[image: UIActivityViewController sheet]

**Pressing Gmail button shows:**

[image: Gmail extension with image attached]

**And the email arrives like this:**

[image: Received email showing malformed attachment]
[image: Unable to open image]

**But, everything is okay if I try to use iOS's Mail.app:**

[image: Mail.app with attached image]
[image: Received email showing correct attachment]

Comment: you found any solution ??

Comment: I don't recall this being solved, it may be working now due to a newer version of Gmail extension or something